# OpenLDAP Disable Alias Dereferencing

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm attempting to configure an OpenLDAP server and need to turn off alias dereferencing.  Has anyone had any experience turning this off and know where to point me? I've attempted to change the ldap.conf file however that is only used by LDAP clients, not servers.

Answer (score 1):

There is **olcMaxDerefDepth** wich is a **database backend parameter**. The default value is 15. According slapd-config(5) man page, this parameter limit the alias dereferencing depth. Setting this parameter to 0 **maybe** can turn off alias dereferencing (I never tried it).

If you are faced with a slow server response problem, there is also the olcTimeLimit global or by user parameter who can the search time limit.